# Update the text value on Canvas after move it with scroll

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to get the text value from a list of canvas.create_text after scrolling the canvas in tkinter.
When I click on a text after move the canvas, I get the original text value ('cause I get the original position) when canvas was created.
I'm trying to get the update position linked with the text and get the desired value after make scrolling in canvas.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

import re

import customtkinter

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='#ffffff')
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.resizable(True, True)


def Example():
    global atras_button2

    def optionmenu_callback():
        global atras_button2
        global listado

        atras_button2.destroy()

        def scroll_start(event):
            canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

        def scroll_move(event):
            canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=2)

        canvasmaster = tk.Canvas(root, width=252, height=512, background="#ffffff")
        canvasmaster.place(relx=0.428, rely=0.48, anchor="center")

        canvas = tk.Canvas(master=canvasmaster, width=250, height=350, background="white")
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0 ,250,1000))
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        def onObjectClick(event):   
            global atras_button2
            global listado

            repais = str(event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y)).replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','')

            diccionariodepaises = {'España':'1','Afganistán':'2','Albania':'3','Alemania':'4','Angola':'5','Anguila':'6','Antigua y Barbuda':'7','Antillas Holandesas':'8','Arabia Saudita':'9',
            'Argelia':'10','Argentina':'11','Armenia':'12','Aruba':'13','Australia':'14','Austria':'15','Azerbaiyán':'16','Bahamas':'17','Bangladés':'18','Barbados':'19','Bélgica':'20','Belice':'21',
            'Benín':'22','Bermudas':'23','Bielorrusia':'24','Bolivia':'25','Bosnia y Herzegovina':'26','Botsuana':'27','Brasil':'28','Brunéi':'29','Bulgaria':'30','Burkina Faso':'31','Burundi':'32'}

            prefix=list(diccionariodepaises.keys())[list(diccionariodepaises.values()).index(repais)]
            print("prefijo", prefix)
            
            textprefijo_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value=prefix)
            textprefijo = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root, textvariable=textprefijo_var, anchor="w", padx=4, font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Lato", size=18),  text_color=("#333333"))
            textprefijo.place(relx=0.374, rely=0.20, anchor="w")

            canvas.destroy()
            canvasmaster.destroy()

            atras_button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, corner_radius=8, height=60, border_spacing=1, border_color="#385974", border_width=2, text="ATRÁS", 
                font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Roboto", size=20), fg_color="#ffffff", text_color=("#385974"), 
                hover_color=("#ffffff", "gray10"), width=60,  anchor="center",  command=lambda:optionmenu_callback())
            atras_button2.place(relx=0.515, rely=0.20, anchor="center")

        diccionariodepaises = {'España':'1','Afganistán':'2','Albania':'3','Alemania':'4','Angola':'5','Anguila':'6','Antigua y Barbuda':'7','Antillas Holandesas':'8','Arabia Saudita':'9','Argelia':'10','Argentina':'11','Armenia':'12','Aruba':'13','Australia':'14','Austria':'15','Azerbaiyán':'16','Bahamas':'17','Bangladés':'18','Barbados':'19','Bélgica':'20','Belice':'21','Benín':'22','Bermudas':'23','Bielorrusia':'24','Bolivia':'25','Bosnia y Herzegovina':'26','Botsuana':'27','Brasil':'28','Brunéi':'29','Bulgaria':'30','Burkina Faso':'31','Burundi':'32'}
        
        for n in range(31):
            taggy = list(diccionariodepaises.keys())[n]
            canvas.create_text(10, (n+1)*30, anchor="w", text=taggy, tags=n+1)
            canvas.tag_bind(n+1, '<ButtonPress-1>', onObjectClick)

        canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", scroll_start)
        canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", scroll_move)


    Entry_textoEMAILreservaBOX= customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, width=250, height=60, font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Lato", size=10), 
        justify='center', placeholder_text_color="#003f5c", fg_color="#ffffff")
    Entry_textoEMAILreservaBOX.place(relx=0.428, rely=0.20, anchor="center")
    Entry_textoEMAILreservaBOX.configure(justify="left", state="disabled")

    atras_button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, corner_radius=8, height=60, border_spacing=1, border_color="#385974", border_width=2, text="ATRÁS", 
        font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Roboto", size=20), fg_color="#ffffff", text_color=("#385974"), 
        hover_color=("#ffffff", "gray10"), width=60,  anchor="center",  command=lambda:optionmenu_callback())
    atras_button2.place(relx=0.515, rely=0.20, anchor="center")



if __name__ == "__main__":

    Example()
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to get the update position linked with the text and get the desired value after make scrolling in canvas, but I got the original text value when canvas is created.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas has two methods to convert window coordinates to canvas coordinates: `canvasx` and `canvasy`. You can pass in `event.x` and `event.y` to get the correct coordinates.

```
x = event.widget.canvasx(event.x)
y = event.widget.canvasy(event.y)

repais = str(event.widget.find_closest(x,y)).replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','')
```

Also, you can greatly simplify the way you're getting the value. Instead of converting the tuple to a string and then replacing the parts you don't want,  just get the first value out of the tuple:

```
x = event.widget.canvasx(event.x)
y = event.widget.canvasy(event.y)

repais = str(event.widget.find_closest(x,y)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan! The problem was solved with your answer!